# MySQL Delete all records except latest N for each user

Tags: mysql, sql, record

I want to keep lastest N records of **each user_id** and delete others.

Structure table "tab":

```
    id (auto increment)
    user_id 
    information
```

If possible, I would like to not delete if a user's number of records is less than N.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you running? `select version()` can tell you.

Comment: Sorry, @GMB it's 5.7.30.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join` in a `delete`:

```
delete t
     from t join
          (select t.*, row_number() over (order by id desc) as seqnum
           from t
          ) tt
          on tt.user_id = t.user_id
     where seqnum > N;
```

This reversely enumerates the rows for a given `user_id` and then deletes those whose enumeration is too large.

I should add that this requires MySQL 8+.

EDIT:

In older versions of MySQL, you can use:

```
delete t
     from t join
          (select u.user_id,
                  (select t2.id
                   from t t2
                   where t2.user_id = t.user_id 
                   order by t2.id desc
                   limit 1 offset N
                  ) as nth_id
           from (select distinct user_id from t) u
          ) tt
          on tt.user_id = t.user_id
     where t.id <= nth_id;
```

Test the subquery before you run the `delete`.  It should be returning the n+1th id for each user.

Comment: Thanks, @Gordon Linoff. It didn't work in version of MySQL I am running.

Answer (score 0):

You can use correlated subquery as follows:

```
Delete from your_table t
 Where N <= (select count(1) 
               from Your_table tt 
              where tt.id < t.id)
```